# What tense should we use for this context?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, sentence-choice

*The scenario:* 
We are outside of governmental office, and it's closed now. But it's understood that they're going to open it some-when soon but it's not understood exactly when. On the wall, near to the door, there's a small piece of metal in which the working hours are written on it. Now my friend looked at it already and I want to ask him about the times that remains, but I can use it at least in three types of tenses (and combinations of them as well):

> How much time remains (or is left) till they **open** the office"?  -
>   *present simple*.
>
> How much time remains (or is left) till they **will open** the
>   office"? - *future simple.*
>
> How much time remains (or is left) till **they're opening** the
>   office"? - *present progressive*
>
> How much time remains (or is left) till **they're going to open** the
>   office?

Which of those should I use in the mentioned scenario?

Comment: The first version is perfectly natural. None of the others are. Alternatively, and *at least* as natural, ***...until the office opens*** (who cares *who* opens it?).

Comment: Thank you. Your choosing in "until" instead of "till" in this context was a personal matter of style or it's more natural in this context?

Comment: *When does it open?*  or *How much longer til it opens?*

Comment: Essentially a personal stylistic choice - but per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How+long+until+we%2CHow+long+till+we%2CHow+long+til+we&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHow%20long%20until%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHow%20long%20till%20we%3B%2Cc0), given my intention was to choose the *most common* option, it seems I made the "right" choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any of those are awkward because of the tense.  "How much time remains" is wordy, and it does not work in all the tenses:

- How much time remains until they open the office?  *Okay but sound oddly formal, don't use  informal "'til" here*
- How long 'til they open the office?  *Better, until/'til both okay*
- When will they open the office?
- When are they opening the office?  *Sounds like opening in the sense of starting a new business.*
- When are they going to open the office?
- When do they open?

Comment: Thank you for your answer (^1+). Can you please me explain the last example please? (="When **to** they open?" Did you not mean to write "When **DO** they open?"?

Comment: @Perplexedfolks yes, fixed typo.

Comment: @Perplexedfolks Also: The answer to any "how long..." version will be a duration, but the answer to "when" could be a duration ("in an hour") or the time ("at 1 o'clock").

Comment: I disagree with *[none]  are awkward because of the tense*. Even if we change the first component to the more common ***How long until / till / til...***, all except the first version seem exceptionally "awkward" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My point was that the problem with the sentences in the question was not a grammatical issue with using different tenses to form the question.

Comment: *My* point was that the problem with the sentences in the question isn't a matter of whether they're "grammatical" or not (I think they all are). It's a matter of *idiomacy* (what people *actually* choose to say, ordinarily).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The headline question is "what tense".  In that case, I think all example tenses are fine (as shown in my examples).  I do not endorse the specific examples in the question.  Are you also disagreeing with *my* examples?  I'm a native speaker who has lived in the midwest and on the west coast.  Are there regions where some of my examples don't work?

Comment: I hadn't even read your examples when I first commented. I'm not really "disagreeing" with any alternatives - I'm simply saying that *to me, at least*, OP's examples #2, #3, and #4 are all relatively awkward and/or uncommon compared to the first. They all *could* occur, obviously - but if OP wants to know which one he "should" use, it must surely be #1. And going outside those 4 possibilities, intransitive ***How long till/until the office opens?*** sounds like a front-runner to me. Many other alternatives "work", but they're far less likely in the real world.